# Is the following fact for laplace matrix true? And how to prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

$A$ is a matrix with $0$ or $1$ element. $L$ is the lapace matrix of $A$. $S$ is a real vector, we define $\mathbb{sign}(S) = [\mathbb{sign}(s_1),...,\mathbb{sign}(s_n)]^T$. I find the following fact that $S^TL\mathbb{sign}(S)>0$ is always true through a large simulation. Is the fact necessary for the matrix metioned above and how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on convention, the sign of zero may be zero or one.

When $\operatorname{sign}(0)=1$, let $D=\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{sign}(S))$. Then $S=Dv$ for some $v\ge0$ and $\operatorname{sign}(S)=D\mathbf1$. Hence $S^TL\operatorname{sign}(S)=v^TDLD\mathbf1$. Since $L$ is Laplacian and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are equal to $\pm1$, $L\le DLD$ entrywise. It follows that $0=L\mathbf1\le DLD\mathbf1$ and in turn, $0\le v^TDLD\mathbf1$.

When $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$, we have $S^TL\operatorname{sign}(S)=u^TM\operatorname{sign}(u)$ where $u$ is the subvector containing all nonzero entries of $S$ and $M$ is the corresponding principal submatrix of $L$. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{sign}(u))$. Then $u=Dv$ for some $v>0$ and $u^TM\operatorname{sign}(u)=v^TDMD\mathbf1$. Similar to the previous paragraph, we have $M\le DMD$ entrywise and hence $M\mathbf1\le DMD\mathbf1$. Note that, as $M$ is a principal submatrix of $L$ and all off-diagonal entries of $L$ are non-positive, every row sum in $M$ is $\ge$ the corresponding row sum in $L$, because there are potentially fewer negative entries. It follows from $0=L\mathbf1$ that $0\le M\mathbf1$. Therefore $0\le M\mathbf1\le DMD\mathbf1$ and in turn, $0\le v^TDLD\mathbf1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have a question. How can this proof be true in my problem where $D=\mathbb{diag}(\mathbb{sign}(S))$?

Comment: @ZhitaoWang $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $\pm1$. Therefore, $DLD$ keeps the diagonal of $L$ unchanged, but possibly flips the signs of some entries of $L$. However, as $L$ is Laplacian, all off-diagonal entries of $L$ are $\le0$. Therefore, when a flip occurs, the sign of the corresponding off-diagonal entry changes from non-positive to non-negative, i.e. it increases.

Comment: Thank you again! I have seen this question. But in fact it should be $D=\mathbb{diag}(\mathbb{sign(S)})$. In this case, the diagonal entries contain $0$. How could I handle this situation?

Comment: I have got it. Thank you!

Comment: @ZhitaoWang Done. See my new edit.